# English phrase/idiom that means "attending an event just for the sake of being seen"

Tags: idioms, phrases, idioms-in-context

I was just wondering what the idiom was for "attending an event just for the sake of being seen there" (along the lines of what a lot of famous people do just for the sake of publicity) .

I am aware that there is a distinct British or English phrase for it but I can't remember it.

Please let me know what the idiom/phrase is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean if it's a duty? "I have to show my face"? "I need to put in an appearance"?

Comment: No @OldBrixtonian . Thank you for responding but that is not what I meant. What I meant was something like a celebrity being seen at a major sporting event just for the sake of publicity knowing that they will be photographed there.

Comment: A photo opportunity? I give up :-)